# Reading from text file using buffer and multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, buffer

Part of a project I am working on requires me to read from a text file of unknown size and put the data into a 10KB buffer. I have to read the file into this buffer in 2KB chunks. I must have 4 threads running simultaneously. The first thread does the reading I just mentioned.

As the thread is reading in 2KB chunks of data into the buffer, the other three threads grab the 2KB chunk read in by the reader and conduct some calculations on it. Once these threads are done they grab the next 2KB chunk and do the same calculations. This is repeated until the entire text file has been read through.

Can anyone give me some guidance as to how to proceed with this part of the project? I know how to multithread. It is just the combination of multithreading and I/O that I have not had experience with before. I have only done simple I/O before.

Comment: When you say "I know how to multithread" are you familiar with condition variables?

Comment: Can the three threads work independently on 1/3 of the 2K chunk each?  If not, there is going to be a big mess of contention.

Comment: If the three threads using the data in the buffer only read the data there will be no contention.

Comment: If the three threads using the data in the buffer only read the data then my question changes to 'where does the output go?'

Answer (score 0):

One simple mechanism might be to have a shared "high water mark" for the 10K buffer.  The thread that reads the file (the I/O thread) will update it at appropriate points, the 'consumer' threads will read it.  It will be protected by a mutex and when the I/O thread updates it it will signal a condition variable.  Only the I/O thread is allowed to write to that variable (while holding a mutex) and the 10KB buffer - the other threads are allowed to read that variable (while holding a mutex) and can read from the buffer - but only up to the point indicated by the high water mark.

Some very rough pseudo code (fill in your own error handling, checking for completion, initialization, etc):

```
pthread_mutex_t mux;
pthread_cond_var_t valid_bytes_updated;

int g_valid_bytes = 0;    // high water mark

char buffer[10 * 1024];

void* io_thread(...)
{
    int offset = 0;

    while (!done) {
        // read the next block of data
        readdata( file_handle, &buffer[offset], 2 * 1024);

        // let consumer threads know there's more data
        offset += 2 * 1024;
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mux);
        g_valid_bytes = offset;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mux);

        pthread_cond_broadcast( &updated);
}


void* consumer_thread(...)
{
    int processed_bytes = 0;

    while (!done) {
        // wait until there's something to do
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mux);
        while (processed_bytes == g_valid_bytes) {
            pthread_cond_wait( &valid_bytes_updated, &mux);
        }
        int valid_bytes = g_valid_bytes;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mux);

        // process the data in range &buffer[processed_bytes] to &buffer[valid_bytes], 
        //  keeping in mind that the range is up to but not including the byte at
        //  &buffer[valid_bytes]

        processed_bytes = valid_bytes;
    }
}
```